# What is the earliest mention of fae being able to literally steal a human's name?

Tags: history-of, fairy

There is a trope circulating on the internet that if a fae (or fairy, elf, etc.) asks for your name, and you give it to them, they can literally take your name from you, leaving you nameless.

How far back does this trope date? Does it appear in any traditional fairy tales, or is it a more recent invention? Are there any citations even from before the 21st century?

"Fae" generally refers to a secretive race of magical pagan creatures in the European tradition, e.g. creatures similar to those called fairies, leprechauns, elves, Aos sí, etc, or modern stories based on such creatures. Basically, any magical creature that would appear in a European fairy tale might qualify. [Here](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Edash/folktexts.html) is a compendium of many authentic fairy tales.

Note that I am looking for mentions of a *fae* stealing the name of a *human*, not the other way around.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it's Ancient Egypt or Sumer, though not sure of the latter, where the idea of name magic appears. There is an Egyptian myth about how Isis used Ra's "true name" to gain power over him. Also, it depends on the "type" of Fae mythology itself. Norse/Germanic/Gaelic elves are quite different from the type we normally associate the word with, so it's a good idea to maybe improve on the question? Not criticism, just observation.

Comment: @AcePL Gods aren't classified as fae, and Ra is not a human either. The question is about fae stealing a *human's* name by wordplay, not someone taking a *fae's* name or a god's name (and not a human using name magic against another human). Rumplestiltskin for example also does not qualify, as it is a human using Rumplestiltskin's name to control him, not the reverse. My suspicion is that the idea that fae would do this is very modern, probably 20th century (maybe even 21st century).

Comment: For what qualifies as fae: it is ambiguous but it generally refers to a secretive race of magical pagan creatures in the European tradition, e.g. creatures similar to those called fairies, leprechauns, elves, Aos sí, etc.

Comment: Yeah, there is a bit missing due to clumsy phone edit - Ra's name stealing is first known instance - "But the True Name magic use by fae I know of is by Daoine Sidhe (Aos Sí) of Gaelic myths."

Comment: Probably in one of Child Ballads, but I forgot which one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_Ballads

Comment: Does it count if a wizard did it, rather than a fae?

Comment: See here: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName and here: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakeAwayTheirName

Comment: @OrangeDog If a wizard counts then we have the naming of Ged in *A Wizard of Earthsea*.  First his birthname is taken away, nameless he undergoes a baptism-type/rebirth ceremony, and finally he is bestowed his true name.

Comment: @DavidW that doesn't sound like the same thing at all.

Comment: @OrangeDog I'd say wizards do qualify, Morgan le Fay from Arthurian legend is a wizard/witch and also clearly a fae. I don't know about this ceremony though, it doesn't sound like the name was exactly stolen, more that he voluntarily changed his name. It might depend on the specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only example I can find of a fae stealing a name because the victim named themselves is [SCP-4000](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/taboo) AKA "taboo", published in **2018**.

In this case the victim names himself "fellow scholar" while conversing with a nameless fae, allowing the fae to take the victim's original name and entire identity. The SCP features many variations of name transference whenever something is named, before this final example.

The SCP Foundation wiki has a couple of other mentions, but they were written after this.

If a wizard counts, rather than a fae, then the video game *Planescape: Torment* (**1999**) has an NPC who suffers this fate after revealing their name to an evil magician.

What *is* an established trope of faery is that [names have power](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName). Knowing something's true name allows control over it in some form. This goes back to ancient Egyptian mythology. *Spirited Away*, SCP-4000, and Arthurian legend would have all had the idea to steal names from this general concept.

Comment: Wizards count. Is there a more detailed description of exactly what happens to this NPC in planescape:torment?

Comment: @causative that's about it, a wizard finds out their name and steals it, cursing them. You get a sidequest to lift the curse.

Comment: What was the NPC's name? https://shrines.rpgclassics.com/pc/planescape/quests.shtml#null has a list of quests, is the quest to lift the curse one of those?

Comment: @causative it's the Reekwind one

Comment: Meh, Ged took away Akaren's name long before P:T. Examples are indeed sure to get back to ancient times.

Comment: @Mithoron from the summary I just read, Ged did not steal her name, so fails at the first criterion. Ged is also not a fairy, so I wouldn't consider it an answer, but OP might. If you are so sure there are examples back to ancient times, simply find one.